# Email Limit exceeded

Tags: email, exception

I am trying to send an email to couple of gmail accounts, I have come across this exception, kindly help me out

> Line: 10, Column: 1
>
> System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: SINGLE_EMAIL_LIMIT_EXCEEDED, Email limit exceeded: []

Answer (score 2):

Single Email Limit per day is 5000 per day for external email ids( email id not of contact,leads,users).

> **Email Limits** 
>   Using the API or Apex, you can send single emails to a
>   maximum of 5,000 external email addresses per day based on Greenwich
>   Mean Time (GMT). Single emails sent using the email author or composer
>   in Salesforce don't count toward this limit. There’s no limit on
>   sending individual emails to contacts, leads, person accounts, and
>   users in your org directly from account, contact, lead, opportunity,
>   case, campaign, or custom object pages.

You might have exceeded the single email limits for your org and so the error.

You can check the limits left by following the below steps:

You can access Workbench here: https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php

> 1. Ensure you are logged into the organization where you want to verify your limits.
> 2. Navigate to https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php
> 3. Accept any oauth prompts to complete authentication
> 4. Select "Jump to REST Explorer"
> 5. Select execute
> 6. From the options presented select:  /services/data/vXX.0/limits
> 7. Select the SingleEmail area to view the daily maximum and remaining calls.